# Using fragments from navigation drawer to overlay activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am having trouble laying a fragment on top of my existing activity. What I am attempting to accomplish is as follows: Open app -> mapView is created -> navigation drawer is created -> button on navigation drawer opens new fragment laying on top on mapView (while mapView not being visible). What is happening is the layout for the fragment is showing, but the white space of the layout is transparent and I am still able to use the map. Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private MapView mapView;
 private LocationListener locationListener;
 private GeometryLayer locationLayer; 
 private Timer locationTimer;

 private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
 private ListView mDrawerList;
 private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

 private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
 private CharSequence mTitle;
 CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;

 List<DrawerItem> dataList;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     setMap();

     initDrawer(savedInstanceState);

 }

 private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         SelectItem(position);

     }
 }

 @Override
 public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
       mTitle = title;
       getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
       mDrawerToggle.syncState();
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
       // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
       if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
             return true;
       }

       return false;
 }

 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
       // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
       mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 }

 public void SelectItem(int possition) {

     Fragment fragment = null;
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     switch (possition) {

     case 0:
         fragment = new ProfileFragment();
         args.putString(ProfileFragment.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                     .getItemName());
         args.putInt(ProfileFragment.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                     .getImgResID());

         break;

     case 1:
           fragment = new ProfileFragment();
           args.putString(ProfileFragment.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                       .getItemName());
           args.putInt(ProfileFragment.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                       .getImgResID());

           break;

     case 4:
           fragment = new SettingsFragment();
           args.putString(SettingsFragment.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                       .getItemName());
           args.putInt(SettingsFragment.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                       .getImgResID());
           break;

     default:
           break;
     }

     fragment.setArguments(args);
     android.app.FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
     frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                 .commit();

     mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
     setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
     mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

}

 @Override
 protected void onStart() {
     super.onStart();

     // 4. Start the map - mandatory.
     mapView.startMapping();

     // Create layer for location circle
     locationLayer = new GeometryLayer(mapView.getLayers().getBaseProjection());
     mapView.getComponents().layers.addLayer(locationLayer);

     // add GPS My Location functionality 
     final MyLocationCircle locationCircle = new MyLocationCircle(locationLayer);
     initGps(locationCircle);

     // Run animation
     locationTimer = new Timer();
     locationTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             locationCircle.update(mapView.getZoom());
         }
     }, 0, 50);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStop() {
     // Stop animation
     locationTimer.cancel();

     // Remove created layer
     mapView.getComponents().layers.removeLayer(locationLayer);

     // remove GPS support, otherwise we will leak memory
     deinitGps();

     // Note: it is recommended to move startMapping() call to onStart method and implement onStop method (call MapView.stopMapping() from onStop). 
     mapView.stopMapping();

     super.onStop();
}

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
 }

 protected void initGps(final MyLocationCircle locationCircle) {
     final Projection proj = mapView.getLayers().getBaseLayer().getProjection();

     locationListener = new LocationListener() {
         @Override
         public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              locationCircle.setLocation(proj, location);
              locationCircle.setVisible(true);

              // recenter automatically to GPS point
              // TODO in real app it can be annoying this way, add extra control that it is done only once
              mapView.setFocusPoint(mapView.getLayers().getBaseProjection().fromWgs84(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()));
         }

         @Override
         public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
             Log.debug("GPS onStatusChanged "+provider+" to "+status);
         }

         @Override
         public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
             Log.debug("GPS onProviderEnabled");
         }

         @Override
         public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
             Log.debug("GPS onProviderDisabled");
         }
     };

     LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
     for(String provider : providers){
         locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10000, 100, locationListener);
     }

 }

 protected void deinitGps() {
     // remove listeners from location manager - otherwise we will leak memory
     LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);    
 }

 // adjust zooming to DPI, so texts on rasters will be not too small
 // useful for non-retina rasters, they would look like "digitally zoomed"
 private void adjustMapDpi() {
     DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
     float dpi = metrics.densityDpi;
     // following is equal to  -log2(dpi / DEFAULT_DPI)
     float adjustment = (float) - (Math.log(dpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) / Math.log(2));
     Log.debug("adjust DPI = "+dpi+" as zoom adjustment = "+adjustment);
     mapView.getOptions().setTileZoomLevelBias(adjustment / 2.0f);
 }

 private void addCartoDbLayer() {

        //  5.1 Define styles for all possible geometry types
        int color = Color.BLUE;
        int minZoom = 5;

        final Bitmap pointMarker = UnscaledBitmapLoader.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.point);
        final StyleSet<PointStyle> pointStyleSet = new StyleSet<PointStyle>();
        PointStyle pointStyle = PointStyle.builder().setBitmap(pointMarker).setSize(0.05f).setColor(color).setPickingSize(0.2f).build();
        pointStyleSet.setZoomStyle(minZoom, pointStyle);

        final StyleSet<LineStyle> lineStyleSet = new StyleSet<LineStyle>();
        LineStyle lineStyle = LineStyle.builder().setWidth(0.04f).setColor(Color.WHITE).build();
        lineStyleSet.setZoomStyle(minZoom, lineStyle);

        final StyleSet<PolygonStyle> polygonStyleSet = new StyleSet<PolygonStyle>(null);
        PolygonStyle polygonStyle = PolygonStyle.builder().setColor(0xFFFF6600 & 0x80FFFFFF).setLineStyle(lineStyle).build();
        polygonStyleSet.setZoomStyle(minZoom, polygonStyle);

        String account = "bitciv";
        String table = "units"; // kihelkonnad_1897, maakond_20120701
        String columns = "cartodb_id,name,iso2,pop2005,area,the_geom_webmercator"; // NB! always include cartodb_id and the_geom_webmercator
        //String columns = "cartodb_id,job,the_geom_webmercator";
        int limit = 5000; // max number of objects
        String sql = "SELECT "+columns+" FROM "+table+" WHERE the_geom_webmercator && ST_SetSRID('BOX3D(!bbox!)'::box3d, 3857) LIMIT "+limit;

        //      String sql2 = "SELECT name, type, oneway, osm_id, the_geom_webmercator FROM osm_roads WHERE type in ('trunk','primary') AND the_geom_webmercator && ST_SetSRID('BOX3D(!bbox!)'::box3d, 3857) LIMIT 500";
        //      String sql2 = "SELECT name, type, oneway, osm_id, the_geom_webmercator FROM osm_roads WHERE the_geom_webmercator && ST_SetSRID('BOX3D(!bbox!)'::box3d, 3857) LIMIT 500";

        CartoDbDataSource cartoDataSource = new CartoDbDataSource(mapView.getLayers().getBaseLayer().getProjection(), account, sql) {

            @Override
            protected Label createLabel(Map<String, String> userData) {
                StringBuffer labelTxt = new StringBuffer();
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : userData.entrySet()){
                    labelTxt.append(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
                }
                return new DefaultLabel("Data:", labelTxt.toString());
            }

            @Override
            protected StyleSet<PointStyle> createPointStyleSet(Map<String, String> userData, int zoom) {
                return pointStyleSet;
            }

            @Override
            protected StyleSet<LineStyle> createLineStyleSet(Map<String, String> userData, int zoom) {
                return lineStyleSet;
            }

            @Override
            protected StyleSet<PolygonStyle> createPolygonStyleSet(Map<String, String> userData, int zoom) {
                return polygonStyleSet;
            }

        };

        GeometryLayer cartoLayerTrunk = new GeometryLayer(cartoDataSource);
        mapView.getLayers().addLayer(cartoLayerTrunk);

    }

 private void setMap(){

    // enable logging for troubleshooting - optional
     Log.enableAll();
     Log.setTag("hellomap");

     // 1. Get the MapView from the Layout xml - mandatory
     mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

     // Optional, but very useful: restore map state during device rotation,
     // it is saved in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() below
     Components retainObject = (Components) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
     if (retainObject != null) {
         // just restore configuration and update listener, skip other initializations
         mapView.setComponents(retainObject);
         return;
     } else {
         // 2. create and set MapView components - mandatory
         mapView.setComponents(new Components());
     }

     // 3. Define map layer for basemap - mandatory.
     // Here we use MapQuest open tiles.
     // We use online data source for the tiles and the URL is given as template. Almost all online tiled maps use EPSG3857 projection.
     RasterDataSource dataSource = new HTTPRasterDataSource(new EPSG3857(), 0, 18, "http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png");

     RasterLayer mapLayer = new RasterLayer(dataSource, 0);

     mapView.getLayers().setBaseLayer(mapLayer);

     adjustMapDpi();

     // Show performance indicator
     //mapView.getOptions().setFPSIndicator(true);

     // Increase raster tile download speed by doing 4 downloads in parallel
     //mapView.getOptions().setRasterTaskPoolSize(4);

     // set initial map view camera - optional. "World view" is default
     // Location: San Francisco 
     // NB! it must be in base layer projection (EPSG3857), so we convert it from lat and long
     mapView.setFocusPoint(mapView.getLayers().getBaseLayer().getProjection().fromWgs84(-122.41666666667f, 37.76666666666f));
     // rotation - 0 = north-up
     mapView.setMapRotation(0f);
     // zoom - 0 = world, like on most web maps
     mapView.setZoom(16.0f);
     // tilt means perspective view. Default is 90 degrees for "normal" 2D map view, minimum allowed is 30 degrees.
     mapView.setTilt(65.0f);

     // Activate some mapview options to make it smoother - optional
     mapView.getOptions().setPreloading(true);
     mapView.getOptions().setSeamlessHorizontalPan(true);
     mapView.getOptions().setTileFading(true);
     mapView.getOptions().setKineticPanning(true);
     mapView.getOptions().setDoubleClickZoomIn(true);
     mapView.getOptions().setDualClickZoomOut(true);

     // set sky bitmap - optional, default - white
     mapView.getOptions().setSkyDrawMode(Options.DRAW_BITMAP);
     mapView.getOptions().setSkyOffset(4.86f);
     mapView.getOptions().setSkyBitmap(
             UnscaledBitmapLoader.decodeResource(getResources(),
                     R.drawable.sky_small));

     // Map background, visible if no map tiles loaded - optional, default - white
     mapView.getOptions().setBackgroundPlaneDrawMode(Options.DRAW_BITMAP);
     mapView.getOptions().setBackgroundPlaneBitmap(
             UnscaledBitmapLoader.decodeResource(getResources(),
                     R.drawable.background_plane));
     mapView.getOptions().setClearColor(Color.WHITE);

     // configure texture caching - optional, suggested 
     mapView.getOptions().setTextureMemoryCacheSize(40 * 1024 * 1024);
     mapView.getOptions().setCompressedMemoryCacheSize(8 * 1024 * 1024);

     // define online map persistent caching - optional, suggested. Default - no caching
     mapView.getOptions().setPersistentCachePath(this.getDatabasePath("mapcache").getPath());
     // set persistent raster cache limit to 100MB
     mapView.getOptions().setPersistentCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024);

    /* // 5. Add simple marker to map. 
     // define marker style (image, size, color)
     Bitmap pointMarker = UnscaledBitmapLoader.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.olmarker);
     MarkerStyle markerStyle = MarkerStyle.builder().setBitmap(pointMarker).setSize(0.5f).setColor(Color.WHITE).build();

     // define label what is shown when you click on marker
     Label markerLabel = new DefaultLabel("San Francisco", "Here is a marker");

     // define location of the marker, it must be converted to base map coordinate system
     MapPos markerLocation = mapLayer.getProjection().fromWgs84(-122.416667f, 37.766667f);

     // create layer and add object to the layer, finally add layer to the map. 
     // All overlay layers must be same projection as base layer, so we reuse it
     MarkerLayer markerLayer = new MarkerLayer(mapLayer.getProjection());
     markerLayer.add(new Marker(markerLocation, markerLabel, markerStyle, null));
     mapView.getLayers().addLayer(markerLayer); */

     // add event listener
     MyMapEventListener mapListener = new MyMapEventListener(this, mapView);
     mapView.getOptions().setMapListener(mapListener);

     // 5. Add CartoDB vector layer to map
     addCartoDbLayer();

 }

 private void initDrawer(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    // Initializing
     dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
     mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
     mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
     mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

     mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                 GravityCompat.START);
     mDrawerList.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);

     // Add Drawer Item to dataList
     dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Profile", R.drawable.ic_action_email));
     dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Messages", R.drawable.ic_action_good));
     dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Statistics", R.drawable.ic_action_gamepad));
     dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_labels));
     dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Invite", R.drawable.ic_action_search));

     adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
             dataList);

     mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

     mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

     getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

     mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                 R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                 R.string.drawer_close) {
           public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                 getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                 invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                                           // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
           }

           public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                 getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                 invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                                           // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
           }
     };

     mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
           SelectItem(0);
     }

 }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.nutiteq.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</FrameLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what is happening is that the white spaces of your top most `Fragment` are not capturing click events. To solve this, you need to make the root `ViewGroup` of the top most `Fragment` clickable. If the  second`Fragment`to be added takes up the whole or most of the screen, it is better to call `remove()` instead of `add()` in your `FragmentTransaction` to avoid this issue completely.

Comment: Would it be better practice to use mapView as a fragment and not an activity as I have here?

Comment: You can use `MapFragment` (or `SupportMapFragment` for backwards compatibility) instead of `MapView`.